# How to join two queries from the same table - Jquery Scroll function + Dependent Ajax Filter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

How to join two queries from the same table?

The problem is I'm not able to JOIN these 2 MySql queries properly. The 1st query is for fetching the data from the database through AJAX and the second one is for AJAX page scroll.

These work individually, but I'm not getting the required output.

**Updated:** I was able to join the queries through union all, but when I select the relevant cities, it doesn't run as it should and also scroll isn't working, neither I'm returning the $output at the last for 'no data'.

Thanks!

PHP Code

```
 <?php  
require'connect_mysqli.php'; 
if(isset($_POST["city_id"], $_POST["limit"], $_POST["start"]))  
 {
      if($_POST["city_id"] != '') {
        $sql = ("SELECT * FROM playschools_8states WHERE city_id = '".$_POST["city_id"]."' limit 0, 5 
        union all SELECT * FROM playschools_8states order by city_id DESC LIMIT ".$_POST["start"].", ".$_POST["limit"].""); 
      } 
      else {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM playschools_8states limit 0, 5"; 
      } 
      $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);  
      $output = '';
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {  
           $output .= '<div class="col-md-12 module">
           <div class="img-thumbnail img-responsive pull-right" style="margin:2px;"><img src="'.$row["logo"].'" /></div>
           <p class="p_title_PS">'.$row["name"].'
           <p class="p_state_city">'.$row["state"].',&nbsp;'.$row["pincode"].' </p>
                <p class="p_rohit_adm"><b>School Type: </b> '.$row["schoolType"].'</p>
                <p class="p_rohit_adm"><b>Co-Ed: </b> '.$row["coed"].'</p>
                <p class="p_rohit_ad"><b></b> '.$row["private"].'</p></div>';
      }   
      if ($output =='') {
          echo 'Sorry! No matching results found';
      }
      else
          echo $output;
 }
 ?>
```

JavaScript

```
<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){               
  $('#state').change(function(){  
       var state_id = $(this).val();  
       $.ajax({  
            url:"fetch_statedd.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{stateId:state_id},
            dataType:"text",
            success:function(data)
            {  
                 $('#city').html(data);  
            }  
       });  
    });  
});
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){               
  $('#city').change(function(){  
       var city_id = $(this).val();  
       $.ajax({  
            url:"ps_load_data.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{city_id:city_id}, 
            success:function(data){  
                 $('#show_playschool').html(data);  
            }  
       });  
  });  
}); 
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 var limit = 7;
 var start = 0;
 var action = 'inactive';
 function load_city_data(limit, start)
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"ps_load_data.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{limit:limit, start:start},
   cache:false,
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#load_data').append(data);
    if(data == '')
    {
     $('#load_data_message').html("No Data Found");
     action = 'active';
    }
    else
    {
     $('#load_data_message').html("<h4>Please wait...</h4>");
     action = "inactive";
    }
   }
  });
 }

 if(action == 'inactive')
 {
  action = 'active';
  load_city_data(limit, start);
 }
 $(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $("#load_data").height() && action == 'inactive')
  {
   action = 'active';
   start = start + limit;
   setTimeout(function(){
    load_city_data(limit, start);
   }, 1000);
  }
 }); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: you can add the results together using `union all`

Comment: Thanks @juergend can you show me please.

Comment: `(select * from ...)  union all (select * from ...)`

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: Thank you! @juergend. Oh I tried it with Inner Join which is for joining 2 tables. 

UNION ALL is giving me T_String error. Let me check

Comment: Yes @MagnusEriksson Thanks for reminding. I will escape the user inputs.

Comment: No. It didn't worked @juergend

Comment: I have updated the question.